# Sandbox Sqlite with EF Core

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I'm making a small web app which currently is using `sqlite` + `EF Core 2.1` for storing data.
Are there any solutions that I can **sandbox my sqlite database file** ?

I mean to load my **sqlite** database with its **data** and **triggers** from my physical **db** file into memory.

Everytime when I turn on/off VS debugger, **database will be refreshed with my existing data in physical file**.

Thank you,

Comment: could you define `sandbox`?

Comment: if it means protect and you have > one client then you should not use sqlite.

Comment: It is just a small web app for some people to use only, therefore, I choose sqlite.

Comment: so more than 1 client? ie > 1 client machine?

Comment: I think it is not the point because my app is in development stage, therefore I and my team members can use `sqlite` just for doing api test. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code that literally does what you asked:

```
var sandboxConnection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=:memory:");
sandboxConnection.Open();

using (var physicalConnection = new SqliteConnection("Filename=physical.db"))
{
    physicalConnection.Open();
    physicalConnection.BackupDatabase(sandboxConnection);
}

optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(sandboxConnection);
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day. I tried you solution and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Move the physical sqlite file outside of the web root in a secure folder. 
[SqliteCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/design/) can also be used to encrypt

Comment: As I understand your answer is to copy the sql db file and point the connection string to the copied file ?

Comment: yes - a shared dir possibly.  the point is to take it out of the web site root for security reasons

Comment: Ok, i'll try your solution first :).